# compare angles of two parallel lines

Tags: geometry

let us consider following  picture

[image]

we  are given that  $AB||CD$,question is what  should be instead of  ? mark?we can create  two triangle by this two parallel lines and  they aim would be  to detect if these two triangle is  similar,suppose  we have created right angle triangle,which means that they would have  one same angle $90$ and if another angle would be also  same,that means that  triangles would be similar,we can calculate adjacent angle of $a$ is $180-a$,does  two  side $AB$ and $CD$  together would create  straight line?i mean if angle $AB$ from ? mark side  adjacent of  $a$=$180$,if it is correct then it means that  at place of ? there should be $a$,please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the place of ? there should be a .
Consider that line AB and CD are parallel while BD is the transversal .

So angle ? ( that is angle ABD ) = a because they are corresponding angles. 
For a proof of why corresponding angles are congruent - [link](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Parallel_Implies_Equal_Alternate_Interior_Angles,_Corresponding_Angles,_and_Supplementary_Interior_Angles)

(And if a=180 then ?=180 and both the line AB and CD will coincide with BD and form a straight horizontal line )

Comment: thanks in advance,because there was  question i have asked it,about shadow and man height and there was  such kind of  assumption,i wanted to be sure